# pandas DataFrame style like Excel Graded color scale conditional formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to render a DataFrame as in Excel when using the Graded color formatting:

[image]

I'm not able to get similar result with Pandas (`v0.23.0`) style:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

shape = (3,3)

np.random.seed(0)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0.,144, size=9).reshape(shape))
df.iloc[0,0] = np.nan
df.iloc[1,1] = 144
df.iloc[0,2] = 0
df[3] = 144

df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn').highlight_null('white')
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks,
Greg

---

**EDIT**

This solution worked:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

def background_gradient(s, m, M, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    rng = M - m
    norm = colors.Normalize(m - (rng * low),
                            M + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(s.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

df.style.apply(background_gradient,
               cmap='RdYlGn',
               m=df.min().min(),
               M=144).highlight_null('white')
```

Comment: Tested first solution and working nice.

Comment: I test it in pandas 0.23.0

Comment: Ok, found the answer based on your duplicate flag. See my edits.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work if there are NaN in the mix. Even though my columns are int32 and float64,  I receive a "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str' "